# Google OAuth 2 Access Token using pure Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I am testing Google OAuth 2.0. I have my Client ID, Client Secret and Auth Code. Now I want to get an access and refresh token.

However, I am able to do that from PHP. But getting **Invalid Grant** error while using Javascript.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href='#' onClick='getAccessToken();'> Get your Access Token </a>
        <pre id="response"> </pre>

        <script>
            function getAccessToken() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        client_id: 'MY CLIENT ID',
                        client_secret: 'MY SECRET',
                        code: 'MY AUTH CODE',
                        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/google-api.html',
                        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#response').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        $('#response').html(e.responseText);
                    }
                });

            }
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Basically I am trying to convert the below PHP Curl POST request to Ajax

```php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
        'code'          => $code,
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    ]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Note: Similar type of questions in stack overflow have many views but yet remained unanswered. The genius developers kindly give your input. I am also stuck since 3 days.

Comment: I think that the request of your Javascript works. So how about using new code by reauthorizing the scopes? When the code cannot be used, such error occurs. The code can be used only one time. Please be careful this. And also, how about modifying `$('#response').html(data);` to `$('#response').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, "  "));`? But I'm not sure the detail information about your situation. So if this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: I tried creating new client, secret and auth code, but no luck. Have you ever tried it in your own? Does it work in your case? I think there is some issue as ajax doesn't work with redirect. But not sure.

Comment: Thank you for replying. After I confirmed that the script worked by setting the variable of `client_id`, `client_secret` `code` and `redirect_uri` in the request of your script, I commented that. But I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. For example, how about using `fetch` instead of `ajax`?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks a lot. You solved my issue within 2 mins. It worked after 3 days. What I was missing is that silly `html(JSON.stringify(data, null, " "));` . When I was clicking for the first time, it was not showing results and I was skipping that unknowingly and the auth code getting invalidated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tankaike. This question was asked 3-4 times in StackOverflow and no one replied it carefully.

Beginners!!! One point to be noted: **Auth Code works only once** :) To get a new access token use refresh token that you have got from the first response

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            crossDomain:true,
            cache : true, 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                client_id: client_id,
                client_secret: client_secret,
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
                grant_type: grant_type,
            },

            success: function (data) {
                $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, " "));;
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $('#response').html(e.responseText);
            }
        });
```